# Converting a model trained and saved with tf.estimator to .pb

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I have a model trained with tf.estimator and it was exported after training as below

```
 serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(
feature_placeholders)
 classifier.export_savedmodel(
r'./path/to/model/trainedModel', serving_input_fn)
```

This gives me a `saved_model.pb` and a folder which contains weights as a `.data` file. I can reload the saved model using

```
predictor = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(r'./path/to/model/trainedModel')
```

I'd like to run this model on android and that requires the model to be in `.pb` format. How can I freeze this predictor for use on android platform?

Answer (score 0):

I don't deploy to Android, so you might need to customize the steps a bit, but this is how I do this:

1. Run `<tensorflow_root_installation>/python/tools/freeze_graph.py` with arguments `--input_saved_model_dir=<path_to_the_savedmodel_directory>`, `--output_node_names=<full_name_of_the_output_node>` (you can get the name of the output node from `graph.pbtxt`, although that's not the most comfortable of ways), `--output_graph=frozen_model.pb`
2. (optionally) Run `<tensorflow_root_installation>/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py` with adequate arguments. Alternatively you can look up the [Graph Transform Tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md) and selectively apply optimizations.

At the end of step 1 you'll already have a frozen model with no variables left, that you can then deploy to Android.